# How to tab past closed modal links? #a11y

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

General accessibility question here. I'm looking for general approach, but will also note that this is in a React app so statefulness is a consideration.

Take the following code example of a list of actions, which open corresponding modals. Ideally, you would be able to tab through the list of actions in sequence - but because the modals have links inside, the tabbing experience is not ideal. Basically, you hit 'action 1' and then tab 6 more times before hitting 'action 2' due to the 5 links contained in the modal.

```
<li class="list__item">
   <!-- modal trigger -->
   <a href="#" class="modal">Action 1</a>

   <!-- modal containing links -->
   <aside class="item__modal modal" id="modal-interview-1">
      <a href="#>Sample 1</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 2</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 3</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 4</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 5</a>
   </aside>
</li>
<li class="list__item">
   <!-- modal trigger -->
   <a href="#" class="modal">Action 2</a>

   <!-- modal containing links -->
   <aside class="item__modal modal" id="modal-interview-2">
      <a href="#>Sample 1</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 2</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 3</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 4</a>
      <a href="#>Sample 5</a>
   </aside>
</li>
```

The question on approach what is the best way to handle hiding the anchor tags from the DOM, or at least from tabbing and screen reading, when a tab is disabled? I've tried adding `disabled` to the anchors, and adding an `aria-focusable="false"` to the modal when it's inactive... but it's not giving me the desired effect of skipping the links.

Thanks for your help with this issue.

Comment: I'm definitely not sure whether that's the best thing to do, but youcould  switch on/off focus by removing/setting `tabindex=-1` from your list items.

Comment: How are you hiding the `item__modal modal` - if you use `display: none` it will work fine, are you using opacity or something? If you are there are workarounds but the easiest way is to change it to `display: none` when not in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aria-focusable="false"` is only for screen readers and not well supported, which is why you are struggling with that.

You have a couple of robust options:-

1. Use `display: none` on the `item__modal modal` and then when you add the `modal--active` override it to `display: block` (or whatever, flex etc.) - `display: none` on a parent element is robust and will always make it's children unfocusable. This will always work and is the best option.
2. Set a `tabindex="-1`" on each link (sadly you can't add it to the parent as it can still get overridden on some screen readers) and change it to `tabindex="0"` when the modal opens.

   ```
   <aside class="item__modal modal modal--active" id="modal-interview-1">
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sample 1</a>
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sample 2</a>
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sample 3</a>
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sample 4</a>
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sample 5</a>
   </aside>
   ```

This will work consistently across all browsers.

### It isn't just the tab key

The reason the above are the only robust options is because screen reader users rarely navigate by the `tab` key.

For example a NVDA user will use 1-6 to navigate by heading levels (H1 - H6) and `K` to navigate by links to get a feel for the page.

### final option (not recommended)

You could intercept the tab key presses and manage focus, but you would need to then add `aria-hidden="true"` to each of the links for the same reason (and change it to `aria-hidden="false"` when the modal is active.

This last option does at least afford you the option of using `opacity: 0` to hide the items etc. if you really need to.

Comment: It sort of sounds like `display: none` is the most effective way for all aspects of the question. We do use a transition effect, which would be the crux of the debate between usable vs pretty.

Comment: If you use a transition then what I normally do is have 2 classes on an item, one to set it to `display: block` but an opacity of 0 and a second to change the opacity that is triggered straight after to 1 with an animation. It is a bit messy but it tends to work. (just reverse it for hiding the item again)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the `inert` attribute. It's currently still in draft (I've heard that it's available in Chrome behind a flag). You can [polyfill the attribute](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/inert-polyfill)

In essence, you'd set `inert` as the element is hidden and all technologies would act as though the links aren't there. There's a [really good demo](https://rawgit.com/GoogleChrome/inert-polyfill/master/demo.html) on the polyfill page that will better illustrate the idea. I think it would solve your issue.

Comment: `inert` is only at proposal stage not draft and adding 8kb of JS for a none stable polyfill (that needs another polyfill for I.E.) does not seem like a good suggestion. Also it won't work at all for a screen reader as it intercepts tab key only and screen readers use multiple shortcuts to get to an item.